# Get sequel generated sql to generate field names without backticks

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, sequel, ruby-1.8.7

I have the following query written in SQL:

```
Select     * 
From       npt_articles 
Inner Join npt_authors 
Inner Join users 
Inner Join npt_teams 
Where      npt_teams.id In (1)
```

and the following sql generated by the sequel gem:

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       `npt_articles` 
INNER JOIN `npt_authors` 
INNER JOIN `users` 
INNER JOIN `npt_teams` 
WHERE      ('npt_teams.id' IN (1))
```

The first returns results, the second one doesn't, if I remove the back-ticks then the second then it generates the same result as the first.

This is the code that generates the second sql:

```
team_articles = user.npt_teams.to_a.inject({}) {|arts,team|
    arts.merge({ team.name =>
    NptArticle.join(:npt_authors).join(:users).join(:npt_teams).where('npt_teams.id' => [team.id]).to_a.uniq})
  }
```

How do I get the query generated without backticks?

Comment: Are you certain the back-ticks are the problem, and not the `WHERE ('npt_teams.id' IN (1))`?  Back-ticks shouldn't cause the issue - the single-quotes, however, should.

Comment: ok, then how do I get sequel to generate it without quotes then?

Comment: Can't help you there, sadly.  I don't know anything about `sequel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
.where(:npt_teams__id => [team.id])
```

Comment: That worked, changing the bit to this also worked: `.where("npt_teams.id IN (#{team.id})")`.Although it now causes the script to hang, it works in mysqlworkbench...